# Java Collections.binarySearch() returns null

Tags: java

I have a list of objects and Comparator which is used for sorting and serching in that list. Collections.binarySearch() return null while it supposed to return an integer value. Here is the code :

```
List<AttribRow> rows =  new ArrayList<AttribRow> ();
AttribRow temp = new AttribRow();
temp.setIndv1((long)22);
rows.add(temp);
temp = new AttribRow();
temp.setIndv1((long)22);
rows.add(temp);
temp = new AttribRow();
temp.setIndv1((long)22);
rows.add(temp);
temp = new AttribRow();
temp.setIndv1((long)23);
rows.add(temp);
temp = new AttribRow();
temp.setIndv1((long)22);
rows.add(temp);

temp = new AttribRow();
temp.setIndv1((long)25);
temp.setId((long)55);
Collections.sort(rows, new CitRowsComparator());
int index = 0;
index = Collections.binarySearch(rows, temp,new CitRowsComparator());
```

AttribRow is entity bean class mapped to the table. It has a field indv1 which is used in comparison.

```
private Long indv1;
public Long getIndv1() {
    return indv1;
}

public void setIndv1(Long indv1) {
    this.indv1 = indv1;
}
```

This is a code for Comporator class

```
public class CitRowsComparator implements Comparator<AttribRow> {
    public CitRowsComparator() {
        super();
    }

    public int compare(AttribRow one, AttribRow two) {
        return one.getIndv1().compareTo(two.getIndv1());
    }
}
```

Collections.binarySearch() alsways returns null. Even when I changed compare() method in Comparator to return 0 it was still returning null. Object temp thaht used as a key is also null after binarySearch envocation. I don't ge any expetions. I tried the same code for other class with one field and it worked fine. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How can `binarySearch` return null when it does not return a type that has a null value?  How do you know that `index` is null and not 0?

Comment: This code works at my machine with removing `temp.setId((long)55);
`

Comment: -1 - This question is reporting patently impossible things.

Comment: Sounds like a good time to use the dbeugger to find out what is actually going wrong. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return type of [`Collections.binarySearch()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,java.lang.Object)) is `int` so this method can't ever return `null`. It might return `0`, but that would be an indication that the object is found at index `0` (i.e. the first element).

Also, there's no way that `temp` is `null` after your call to `Collections.binarySearch()` since that method can't modify the value of `temp` (as Java is not pass-by-reference).

When I try your code `index` is `-6` after `binarySearch` returns, indicating that `temp` is not in the collection (which is expected, as no `AttribRow` object with `indv1` value `25` is in there) and would be inserted at position `6` to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Note: AttribRow with Indv1 25 is not added to list, your code is missing `rows.add(temp);` after `temp.setIndv1((long) 25);`.

Additionally, I think re-assign Object `temp = new AttribRow()` is error-prone practice.

Answer (score 0):

I´m getting -6 with your code too...and why you use so many 22 Indv1? according to this you will have the doubt of which object is the correct:

*Searches the specified list for the specified object using the binary search algorithm. The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the specified comparator (as by the Sort(List, Comparator) method, above), prior to making this call. If it is not sorted, the results are undefined. **If the list contains multiple elements equal to the specified object, there is no guarantee which one will be found.***